# $W^{m,p}(\Omega) = H^{m,p}(\Omega)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ an open set, we define the sobolev space:

$$
W^{m,p}(\Omega) = \{u \in L^p(\Omega): D^\alpha u \in L^p(\Omega) \ \mbox{in the sense of distributions with} \ |\alpha| \le m\}
$$

Considering $C^m(\bar{\Omega})$ with the norm:
$$
||\varphi||_{m,p} = \bigg(\sum_{|\alpha|\le m}\int_{\Omega}||D^\alpha \varphi||_{L^p(\Omega)}^p \bigg)^{1/p}
$$
We define $H^{m,p}(\Omega)$ as the completion of $C^m(\bar{\Omega})$ according to this norm. My question is, $H^{m,p}(\Omega) = W^{m,p}(\Omega)$? If so, how to show it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the answer is no:
Let $\Omega = (-1,0) \cup (0,1)$ and $m = 1$, $p = 2$. Then,
$f = \chi_{(0,1)}$
belongs to
$W^{1,2}(\Omega)$,
but due to the jump at $t = 0$, it does not belong to $H^{1,2}(\Omega)$.
(Note that convergence in $H^{1,2}(\Omega)$ implies uniform convergence due to $n = 1$. Hence, all functions in $H^{1,2}(\Omega)$ are continuous at $t = 0 $).

If you have some regularity of $\Omega$, the result should be true,
but I do not have a reference.

Further, the result is unconditionally true if you replace
$C^m(\bar\Omega)$ by $C^m(\Omega) \cap W^{m,p}(\Omega)$.
This is the famous $H = W$ paper by Meyers and Serrin.

Comment: Thank you very much. If $\Omega$ is a smooth bounded limited domain, do you think equality is worth?

Comment: Yes it should be true in this case. But as already said, I don't know a handy reference. The result should be in most PDE books.